# Collections.sort does nothing to my LinkedList

Tags: java, sorting

So I'm attempting to sort my LinkedList that contains Objects of my Student class, That contain names id# as a string, and a gpa double. I want to sort by the name.

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>, Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String gNumber;
    private double gpa;


    public Student(String name, String gNumber, double gpa){
        this.name = name;
        this.gNumber = gNumber;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        return this.name.toLowerCase().compareTo
            (s.getName().toLowerCase());
}
```

This is my LinkedList class and the method that attempts to sort

```
public class LinkedList extends AbstractList implements Serializable{
    //some code

    public void Sort(){
        Collections.sort(this, new Comparator<Student>() {
            public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                return s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
            }
        });
    }
```

However once I actually attempt to sort it, there is no change whatsoever, I get no errors or anything it just acts as nothing happened. I follow the process with my debugger and it calls the method correctly and goes into the methods code but nothing actually happens to my LinkedList. Any Ideas?

EDIT: here's my set (insert) method:

```
public void insert(Student student){
    //case where input is null
    if(student.getName() == null || student.getGNumber() == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    Node temp = head;
    //case where there is no list
    if(head == null){
        head = new Node(student, null);
        tail = head;
        count = 1;
    }

    //case where top has existing Nodes
    else{
        //brings reference to end of list
        while(temp.getNext() != null)
            temp = temp.getNext();

        temp.setNext(new Node(student, null));
        tail = temp;
        count ++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `compareTo` method defined in `Student` class instead of re-implement the functionality in `compare` method?

Comment: Fix the unknown part hidden under `//some code`? Why isn't your list generic? Why doesn't it respect Java naming conventions? Why do you use a comparator since your Student class is comparable?

Comment: We need to see `//some code` especially the `set` method.

Comment: I guess I was just trying anything, even if I don't use a Comparator and just use the compareTo and only call Collection.sort(this); nothing happens

Comment: Collections.sort() sorts any kind of List. List doesn't have any insert() method. So your insert() method is completely irrelevant: Collections.sort() won't ever call it.

Comment: I didn't think it mattered, but it seems that's what pbabcdefp wanted to see, from my impressions of the Collection.sort() the only snippets of code that should matter are the ones originally provided

Comment: I don't think you understand how `Collections.sort` works. It uses methods of `List`. I think the main ones used are `get` and `set`. It won't use your `insert` method unless this is called by `set`.

Comment: Collections.sort, in 1.7 is implemented with toArray, listIterator and set on the iterator. So you need to check these methods.

Comment: @JPMoresmau If you extend `AbstractList` the more complicated methods have default implementations. You can get `Collections.sort` to work just by overriding `size`, `get` and `set`.

Comment: I don't want to be harsh, but it seems you don't really understand basic concepts like inheritance. So implementing a complex generic data structure like a LinkedList and its Iterator is a task that is much too complex for you at the moment. BTW, Java already has a functional LinkedList class. Also, the javadoc of AbstractList says: "For sequential access data (such as a linked list), AbstractSequentialList should be used in preference to this class.". Your class will work if you properly extends AbstractList, but it will be horribly slow.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes i'm aware there is a LinkedList class, and yes I understand inheritance. The reason I'm struggling so much is because this is for a University assignment with annoying instructions asking me to create a program in a very specific way that wouldn't be the normal way of doing things.

Comment: @Itheyln then why isn't your class generic? And why do you show us an irrelevant insert() method? Why don't you show us the relevant methods, i.e. the methods that are defined in AbstractList and that you must implement?